# jQuery How to use Autocomplete function when rows are added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

[image][image: Autocomplete works fine if dynamic div are not added]I am trying to autocomplete input field on dynamically added rows . But it throw an error of `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function`.

Reference : http://jsfiddle.net/r08m8vvy/2/

## HTML

```
<div class="section-content trip-content" >
    <div class="row">
        <form class="cn-form form-horizontal " onsubmit="return false" role="form" data-listing-id="">
            <input type="hidden" name="trip_id" value="">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 trip-details">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 trip-details-mobile">
                    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Trip ID" class="form-control consigner-trip-id" id="consignerTripDetails" autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 trip-details-mobile">
                    <input type="text" name="vehicle_no" placeholder="Vehicle No" class="form-control" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 trip-details-mobile">
                    <input type="text" name="load_type" placeholder="Load Type" class="form-control" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 trip-details">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 trip-details-mobile">
                    <textarea type="text" name="loading_supervisor" placeholder="Loading Supervisor" class="form-control" readonly></textarea>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

## jQuery

```
$("#addTripRows").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tripDetailHTML = '<div class="row"><form class="cn-form form-horizontal" onsubmit="return false" role="form" data-listing-id=""><input type="hidden" name="trip_id" value=""><div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 trip-details"><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 trip-details-mobile"><input type="text" name="" placeholder="Trip ID" class="form-control consigner-trip-id" id="consignerTripDetails" autofocus></div><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 trip-details-mobile"><input type="text" name="vehicle_no" placeholder="Vehicle No" class="form-control" readonly></div><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 trip-details-mobile"><input type="text" name="load_type" placeholder="Load Type" class="form-control" readonly></div></div><div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 trip-details"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 trip-details-mobile"><textarea type="text" name="loading_supervisor" placeholder="Loading Supervisor" class="form-control" readonly></textarea></div></div></form><button class="remove_field v2-button">Remove</button></div>';
  if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
   $(wrapper).append(tripDetailHTML);
   $( "input[id="+ x +"]" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableAttributes
     }); 
  } 
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
    x--;
});
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your html markup including script references. Most likely you are referencing JQuery-UI.js before JQuery.js

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai yeah that what fiddle i am using as reference.

Comment: @MasterYoda is it a problem if i use Jquery-ui.js before Jquery.js ?

Comment: @TanmoySarkar Absolutely. JQuery-ui relies on the JQuery framework being available first, its also the same for the likes of Bootstrap.js and any JQuery plugins, they all require JQuery to be loaded.

Comment: @MasterYoda autocomplete function works fine when i use it first time without clicking add button. when it added dynamically it creates problem.  what error is in my code ?

Comment: @TanmoySarkar Nothing is wrong with it. What browser are you testing on? Try another

Comment: @MasterYoda google chrome i am using .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reference `jQuery.min.js` **before** `jQuery-ui.min.js`.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

`jQuery-ui.min.js` relies on the Jquery framework.

Answer (score 0):

First you go with the similar problem http://jsfiddle.net/r08m8vvy/140/

```
In the above jsfiddle I've removed the jQuery-ui, check the console.
```

Here you go with the solution

```
You are missing jQuery-ui library
```

Adding both `CSS` & `JavaScript`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Make sure the order of the files should be same.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar Please share your all the library file linking. Definitely we will help you out.

Comment: @shailaditya it works fine if rows are not added dynamically. but throw an error on added another row. I have added an image snippet please check.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar Please share the error screenshot. I'm unable to see the error message.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar You are getting error because the `id` that you are targeting `$( "input[id="+ x +"]" ).autocomplete({` as `x` is not present in dom. You need to change the code.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar If you provide more code in jsfiddle, will give you a solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156877/discussion-between-tanmoy-sarkar-and-shiladitya).